# Scroll function is not working in android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-layout

In my android application i'm using HTML and javascript, in the home page footer has a link for another html page which has accordion function(shown in this [link](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=199890))

The Problem is if i open this html page in browser scroll option is available for moving up & down, when i tried it in android emulator scrolling function is diabled and also i can't able to move downwards.Here i included my javascript

```
screen_height = screen.height + 120;
            guide_content_height = screen_height - 245;
            guide_div_height = screen_height - 160;

            $('#guide_content').load("accordion_page.html").css("height", guide_content_height).css('overflow', 'scroll');

            $("#guide_collapsed_btn").click(function() {
                $("#guide_div").css('height', guide_div_height);
                $("#guide_div").show();
                $("#footer").hide();
            });

            $("#guide_expanded_btn").click(function() {
                $("#footer").show();
                $("#guide_div").hide();
            });
```

"guide" is the id given for the footer.